# Show tags selection similar to category selection in WordPress

Tags: widgets, tags

Is there anyway we can display tags similar to category selection in **WordPress dashboard** when editing/adding posts? If we go to publish a new post, we can see a list of categories as checkbox, I want to have similar thing for tags instead of searching for tags I want to have a checkbox.

I do not have any custom post types or anything, just regular WordPress posts.

Any ideas how to achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a plugin, there's a really good explanation from CSS Tricks about how to convert tags from "flat" to "hierarchical".

https://css-tricks.com/how-and-why-to-convert-wordpress-tags-from-flat-to-hierarchical/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this one could help you:

https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/checkbox-for-taxonomies/

Answer (score 0):

I found this after hours so I figured I share the finding
Plugin [Select All Categories and Taxonomies, Change Checkbox to Radio Buttons](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/select-all-categories-and-taxonomies-change-checkbox-to-radio-buttons/) by Moove Agency

[image: preview result checkboxes]